# Socket.io won't propagate/emit a string

Tags: angular, express, socket.io

I am following this tutorial:

https://codingblast.com/chat-application-angular-socket-io/

Everything works up until the last step, *Communicating with other users*.

This is my index.js:

```
let express = require('express')
let app = express();

let http = require('http');
let server = http.Server(app);

let socketIO = require('socket.io');
let io = socketIO(server);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('user connected');
    socket.on('new-message', (message) => {
        console.log(message);
        io.emit(message);
    });
});

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`started on port: ${port}`);
});
```

I left the console.log there on purpose to see if the messages were still coming, which they are.

Then, this is my app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChatService } from '../chat.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  message: string;
  messages: string[] = [];

  constructor(private chatService: ChatService) {
  }

  sendMessage() {
    this.chatService.sendMessage(this.message);
    this.message = '';
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Starting...');
    this.chatService
        .getMessages()
        .subscribe((message: string) => {
          console.log('message sent');
          this.messages.push(message);
        });
  }
}
```

I get the `console.log('Starting...');` but it never reaches the `console.log('message sent');` part in the console.

Here is chat.service.ts too:

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class ChatService {
    private url = 'http://localhost:3000';
    private socket;

    constructor() {
        this.socket = io(this.url);
    }

    public sendMessage(message) {
        this.socket.emit('new-message', message);
    }

    public getMessages = () => {
        return Observable.create((observer) => {
            this.socket.on('new-message', (message) => {
                observer.next(message);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I don't see anything wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that's going wrong is your `io.emit` in your server. You're only passing the message in, but the first parameter of `io.emit` is the event. Simply add `'new-message'` as first parameter and the messages will arrive in your client `socket.on('new-message', ...`

```
socket.on('new-message', (message) => {
    console.log(message);
    io.emit('new-message', message);
});
```